# Spring JPA "PersistentEntity must not be null" with aggregate DTO

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

My summary DTO is throwing PersistentEntity must not be null! I'm using a summary DTO to return sum() and count() aggregates. I added custom queries to the source repository interface.

```
public interface SettlementHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<SettlementHistory, String> {

  @Query("SELECT new com.x.service.report.dto.CategoryAmountSummary(h.organizationName, count(h.id), sum(h.rebateAmount)) FROM SettlementHistory h WHERE h.fundDate BETWEEN :rangeStart AND :rangeEnd GROUP BY h.organizationName ORDER BY h.organizationName")
  List<CategoryAmountSummary> summarizeRebateAmountByOrganizationWhereFundDateIsBetweenOrderByFundDate(
        @Param("rangeStart") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'") Date rangeStart,
        @Param("rangeEnd") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'") Date rangeEnd
  );
```

The method results in this error:

```
  ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : PersistentEntity must not be null!
```

I would return the entity class if not for my need to have a count for each category. How else can I go about this?

Comment: other repository methods work fine I guess? Do you have a complete example on Github or similar?

Comment: @JensSchauder, yes, the repository returns the SettlementHistory entity fine using standard JPA queries. It is simply the fact that I am trying to return a non-entity DTO with a custom query. JPA (or Data Rest?) doesn't know how to handle the DTO type. Today I'll try switching that to native SQL to see if that helps. If not, over the weekend I can build an example in GitHub. I was hoping this was a common enough use case that the solution would be general knowledge.

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace? At least the Spring Data JPA side SHOULD work I think. Not sure if spring data rest as further requirements.

Comment: @JensSchauder - Here is the stacktrace.  [ 2018-06-02 17:24:05.090 ERROR [report-service,5b4a1f1145b4f96c,3f4f7fd2f948ba94,true] 22 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : PersistentEntity must not be null!
 [ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
 [ at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
 [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource$Builder.<init>(PersistentEntityResource.java:140) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 [ at

Comment: [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource$Builder.<init>(PersistentEntityResource.java:123) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource.build(PersistentEntityResource.java:115) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:74) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]

Comment: [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:107) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 [ at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:78) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/:na]

Comment: Can you please put it in the question. Formatted as code, so one can read it properly without guessing where the line breaks go?

Comment: @JensSchauder - Sorry about the logs. The problem is with Spring Data Rest, not Spring JPA, because my junit test passes. I think I will simply add a rest controller and not bother with Spring Data Rest. Here is the project [https://github.com/smitchell/SpringJpaAggregation].

Answer (score 0):

In the end, Spring Data Rest didn't like the repository returning a different object type. To get around the problem I added a Rest Controller that, in turn, called the aggregation method on the repository. It was able to return the summary DTO without problems.